# Unity Multi Objects with same scripts issue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting

I have like 20 objects with the same script. And the problem that when I want to set a value for every each object only one respond to the script. here is the objects main script

```
[SerializeField]
private int Id = 0;

public void SetId(int num)
{
    Id = num;
}

public int ReturnId()
{
    return Id;
}
```

And here where they are called:

```
private void DeterminedWallColor()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _colorType.Length; i++)
        {
            switch (_colorType[i])
            {
                case 1:
                    _wId.SetId(_colorType[i]);
                    break;

                case 2:
                    _wId.SetId(_colorType[i]);
                    break;

                case 3:
                    _wId.SetId(_colorType[i]);
                    break;

                case 4:
                    _wId.SetId(_colorType[i]);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you shouldn't be using a switch statement. The code you have right now will always match the first case because all the cases below it are the same as the first case and will always be the same as the firsts case because it is the same code/expression in all the cases you are checking for.

Also since you want to set a value for each gameObject(assuming you want to set the Id), you would need to loop thru all the gameObjects first, and then set each _colorType per gameObject, according to what you want/need. (I cannot provide code example because your question was vague, and you did not provide context for your code examples such as "_colorType". I cannot tell where that variable came from since you did not provide the variable implementation)